# <%# %> is not working now in any NEW aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using `<%# %>` expressions a lot to set my Text property on a number of controls.  Now for some reason the code is not being fired in the .aspx pages. If we do it on the code behind it works fine. Has anyone ever seen this issue?  We are data binding from a static class in the Classes Folder on the UI root.

Example that is not working now.  On other pages that are ALREADY added to our solution and working... it works fine and hits the code behind function when we set a break point.

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="label1" CssClass="labelFieldCSS"
          Text='<%# UIHelper.MyFunction(Request.Path.ToString()) %>' ></asp:Label>
```

I also have my namespace set in my aspx page

```
<%@ Import Namespace="YourNamespaceForYourUIHelper" %>
```

Comment: Copy one of the expressions that are working on other pages, then use it on this new page.

Comment: That is what we did, John. No luck though. It is very weird. I will try <%= %> tomorrow at work instead of <%# %>

Comment: Also, try `Text='<%# "abc" %>'`

Comment: Is the label inside a gridview?

Comment: Nope - in this case it isn't. We have some that are though, and they are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="label1" CssClass="labelFieldCSS"
          Text="<%= UIHelper.MyFunction(Request.Path.ToString()) %>" ></asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replace the Single quote with Double quote:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="label1" CssClass="labelFieldCSS"
        Text="<%= UIHelper.MyFunction(Request.Path.ToString()) %>">  
</asp:Label>
```

Answer (score -1):

C#:

```
public class UIHelper
{ 
   public static string MyFunction(string path)
  {
      returnString.Format("{0} is your path.",path);
  }
}
```

ASPX:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="label1" CssClass="labelFieldCSS">
  <%= UIHelper.MyFunction(Request.Path) %>
</asp:Label>
```